# What's difference between Python patch version?

Tags: python, python-3.5, versioning

Like the difference between `Python 3.5.2` and `Python 3.5.4`.

According to the New Feature description, no new feature added to `Python 3.5.2` from `Python 3.5.2`

So, What does `Python 3.5.4` have done?

- [New features of `Python 3.5.2`](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.5.2/)
- [New features of `Python 3.5.4`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-354/)

Comment: Both pages link to the changelog.

Comment: In general patch versions are for bug fixes, new features would appear in a minor or major version. See e.g. https://semver.org/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new patch version is released, the release page lists what the *minor* version added (so what is new in the 3.5 series here), not the patch level.  Path levels usually only include bug fixes, not new features.

The patch level changes are listed in the linked changelog:

- [3.5.2 changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-5-2-final)
- [3.5.4 changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-5-4-final)

It looks like the 3.5.2 release page is missing the changelog link; that's an oversight, a bug in the release process if you will.

The changelog is generated from text files in the [`Misc/NEWS.d` directory](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Misc/NEWS.d) of the Python source code repository. When browsing these files on GitHub, do look at the *raw* file contents; the GitHub ReST renderer doesn't show the embedded metadata fields attached to each entry.